# Adding linebreak in loop

Tags: asp.net

I use the following code to add smoe fileupload controls on my page. I'd like a line break between each one, but am having trouble getting it to work.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 2
        Dim fileupload As FileUpload = New FileUpload
        fileupload.ID = "FileUp" & i
        placeUpload.Controls.Add(fileupload)
    Next
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 2
    Dim fileupload As FileUpload = New FileUpload
    fileupload.ID = "FileUp" & i
    placeUpload.Controls.Add(fileupload)
    placeUpload.Controls.Add( new LiteralControl("<br />") )
Next
```